# Entity Framework Core Parent Child items in the same model, children node returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a parent and child property inside one domain model.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual TestModel parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TestModel> children { get; set; }
}
```

When I write `OnModelCreating` event as below:

```
builder.Entity<TestModel>().HasOne(b => b.parent).WithMany(a => a.children).HasForeignKey(b => b.ID);
```

In debug mode children node returns hierarchical same and I get 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'parent' with type TestModel' error on JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

When I change `OnModelCreating` event as below:

```
builder.Entity<TestModel>().HasOne(b => b.parent).WithMany(a => a.children).HasForeignKey(b => b.ParentID);
```

Then children property returns null. How can I solve this problem? How can I load children property correctly?

I hope somebody can help me.

PS: TestModel not in any context so I cant Include. I create a sql query and get using FromSql()

Comment: I suppose when you use b.ID the link is ID field, but when you use ParentID you are using another information, so you can have zero rows

Comment: Are you using .Include(x => x.children) when getting the entities?

Comment: Seems like your issue is with JSON.NET rather than Entity Framework. It doesn't seralise self-referencing objects by default. Check here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm

Comment: Sorry, TestModel not in any context so I cant Include. I create a sql query and get using FromSql()

Answer (score 2):

The second is the right one, but I suspect that when loading, you are not eagerly fetching the children. Try this:

```
var one = context.Set<TestModel>().Include(x => x.children).FirstOrDefault();
```

Another option is to use lazy loading. See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data.

Comment: Sorry, TestModel not in any context so I cant Include. I create a sql query and get using FromSql()

Comment: You can use Include with FromSql: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql. Use Set and then call FromSql in it.

Comment: var one = context.Set<TestModel>().Include(x => x.children).FromSql(sql).FirstOrDefault();

I tried this but I got an error like :
'Invalid object name 'TestModel'.'

Comment: That's because the name of the table does not match the name of the class. How are you using FromSql, from where are you calling it?

Comment: After your suggestion I got syntax error  of course, I'm newbie on ef :)  so I tried something like this:

var queryable = uow.Repository<TestModel>().Query();
var model = queryable .FromSql(sql).Include(x => x.children);

and I got same error again:  'Invalid object name 'TestModel'

Comment: What does Query return, a DbSet? Also, can you show your SQL query, or a simplified version?

Comment: Actually I just want to create a tree and I have to return a json something like that.



  {
    "ParentID": null,
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Node name 1",
    "expanded": true,
    "leaf": false,
    "loaded": true
  }


  
  So I create a SQL query that returns all the information on my TestModel. My sql query consists of several unions like 'SELECT NULL AS ParentID,ID,s.Test,expanded,leaf, loaded FROM dbo.TestDB'.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answers. I didn't find a solution in this way. I decided to use database tables and their relations not a sql query. I guess it will be more correct way. Thank you so much again.